# how to add both number value when the plus sign is click

Tags: javascript

I want to click on a button that has a number value and by clicking the '+' button I want both that value to add and by hitting the "enter" button I want the answer to display. How do I do this?

but there will be other expression not only "+" and i want if the user click the "+" it add the numbers and if user click "-" it subtract the numbers

link to code : https://jsbin.com/gikuped/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
var num1 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].value;
var num2 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].value;
var numPlus = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[2].value;
var Equal = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[2].value;


function btn(event){
    var theTarget = event.target;
    //testing
    alert(theTarget.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u dont need to call event here to add the value just add both value when function call

```
function btn(event){
    var theTarget = event.target.value;
    var val
    if(theTarget === '+') {
        val = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) 
    }else if(theTarget === '-') {
       val = parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2) 
    }else if(theTarget === '*') {
       val = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2) 
    }else if(theTarget === '/') {
       val = parseInt(num1) / parseInt(num2) 
    }
    alert(val);
}
```

as your value receives as string u just have to make it integer (which reason i use parseInt() method ) otherwise it will concat both string

Hope it help

Comment: but there will be other expression not only "+" and i want if the user click the "+"  it add the numbers and if user click "-" it subtract the numbers

Comment: u can check the sign and based on that u will do ur operation